# Django: Messages enum options

Tags: python, django, enums, django-messages

I have a view that handles a variety of forms to manage objects (e.g rename, delete, etc.). For each action I want to define a success and error message such that I do not need to have the message text written directly in the view. Rather I want to do something like this:

**CURRENT**

```
def manage(request):

   ...

   if form.is_valid():
      ...
      messages.success(request, 'Instance rename successful')
   else:
      messages.error(request, 'Instance rename failed')
```

**WHAT I WANT**

```
def manage(request):

   ...

   if form.is_valid():
      ...
      add_message(request, messages.success.rename)
   else:
      add_message(request, messages.error.rename)
```

This is a simple example but I would have more complex messages that I would like to abstract out of the view and simply reference them as shown in the second example.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: You could create a class and write all your constants in there. Just import the class and reference your strings.